# How to npm prune and avoid the removal of a file: dependency?

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I have a local npm package (a node.js/electron add-on) that we install via the file.

```
npm i --save my_package-1.0.0-beta.1.tgz
```

The package.json file lands up looking like this;

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "my_package": "file:my_package-1.0.0-beta.1.tgz",
    ...
  },
}
```

The module is used in the code, extensively.

When I run `npm prune`, the package is removed from `node_modules`. How can I configure or use `npm prune` to not remove this package?

---

Some notes from the comments;

- Ultimately this is part of a workflow from dev to "test" builds for local device deployments and testing. On the build server, this issue doesn't really pop up since we only install for `production` and package from there (i.e. with no `prune`).
- This dependency is part of the production dependencies, the solution must maintain that fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During a recent update to the environment, this was retested. It was found that `npm` now (as of [`npm@4.2.0`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V7.md#7.10.0) installed with node v 7.10.0 and [`npm@4.6.1`](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v4.6.1), "latest") does seem to preserve the `file:` dependency. In addition the `--production` flag works as expected as well.

It is not known exactly when this begin to work or was supported, but it may be circa [`npm@4.1.0`](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v4.1.0); in particular the rewrite to use the [updated `prune` plumbing](https://github.com/npm/npm/commit/981ce6395e7892dde2591b44e484e191f8625431).

---

To update `npm` to the [latest version](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node);

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```